# how to prove that a natural number n > 1 is prime if and only if n divides (n-2)! - 1?

Tags: proof-verification

how to prove that a natural number n > 1 is prime if and only if n divides (n-2)! - 1?
I know it is a 'iff' questions so that it need to be proved by both directions, and I tried to prove by contradiction or contrapositive but still did not figure it out.

Comment: do you wilson theorem

Comment: yes, this equation is followed by the wilson and fermat throrem

Comment: $(n-1)!=(n-1)(n-2)!$ and $n-1\equiv -1\pmod{n}$

Comment: Wilson's theorem states that a natural number  $n $ is a prime number if and only if
$$(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod n$$
   
$$(n-1)(n-2)! \equiv -1 \pmod n$$

Answer (score 1):

Wilson's theorem states that a natural number  $n $ is a prime number if and only if
$$(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod n$$

$$(n-1)(n-2)! \equiv -1 \pmod n$$

$$(n-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

Answer (score 1):

Wilson's Theorem:

$n$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow (n-1)!+1\equiv 0(\mod n)$

But as $(n-1)!+1\equiv(n-1)((n-2)!-1)(\mod n)$ and gcd$(n,n-1)=1$, then

$(n-2)!-1\equiv0(\mod n) \Leftrightarrow (n-1)!+1\equiv0(\mod n) \Leftrightarrow n$ is prime